# DSiWin32.DSiGetHtmlFormatFromClipboard not working?

Tags: html, delphi, clipboard, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am trying to use the `DSiGetHtmlFormatFromClipboard` function from the well known [DSiWin32](http://gp.17slon.com/gp/dsiwin32.htm) library.

Edit: There is a much newer version of `DSIWin32.pas` 1.94 from 2016-10-19 which is contained in the current version of OmniThreadLibrary_3.07.1. The one I've linked to in the first line of my question is much older: 1.66 from 2012-04-20. However, also in this newer version of `DSIWin32.pas` the function `DSiGetHtmlFormatFromClipboard` does not work although I've made sure that no other clipboard programs are running.

So I put some text on the clipboard which includes the HTML format e.g. by copying some text from Chrome web-browser.

And then I use this code to get the HTML format from the clipboard:

```
if DSiWin32.DSiIsHtmlFormatOnClipboard then 
begin
   CodeSite.Send('HTML-Format string:', DSiWin32.DSiGetHtmlFormatFromClipboard);
end;
```

While the `DSiIsHtmlFormatOnClipboard` function does work (it gives back `True` if there is HTML Format on the clipboard and gives back `False` if there is no HTML Format on the clipboard), the `DSiGetHtmlFormatFromClipboard` function always gives back an empty string although there is HTML Format in the clipboard:

[image]

So I debugged `function DSiGetHtmlFormatFromClipboard: string;` in `DSiWin32.pas`:

On this line:

```
hClipData := GetClipboardData(GCF_HTML);
```

`hClipData` is always `0`, so the following code is not executed.

`GetClipboardData` is a function from `Winapi.Windows` and according to [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649039(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Retrieves data from the clipboard in a specified format. The clipboard
>   must have been opened previously.

Which is the case in the `DSiWin32` code.

So why does the `DSiGetHtmlFormatFromClipboard` always give back an empty string?

OS: Windows 7 x64

---

`GetLastError` retrieved immediately after the line `hClipData := GetClipboardData(GCF_HTML);`:

> ERROR_CLIPBOARD_NOT_OPEN 1418 (0x58A) Thread does not have a
>   clipboard open.

This is strange because the preceding line is: `Win32Check(OpenClipboard(0));` and it does not fail.

Here is the relevant parts of the MCVE:

```
var
  GCF_HTML: UINT;

function DSiIsHtmlFormatOnClipboard: boolean;
begin
  Result := IsClipboardFormatAvailable(GCF_HTML);
end; { DSiIsHtmlFormatOnClipboard }

function DSiGetHtmlFormatFromClipboard: string;
var
  hClipData       : THandle;
  idxEndFragment  : integer;
  idxStartFragment: integer;
  pClipData       : PChar;
begin
  Result := '';
  if DSiIsHtmlFormatOnClipboard then
  begin
    Win32Check(OpenClipboard(0));
    try
      hClipData := GetClipboardData(GCF_HTML);
      if hClipData = 0 then
        RaiseLastOSError;
      pClipData := GlobalLock(hClipData);
      Win32Check(assigned(pClipData));
      try
        idxStartFragment := Pos('<!--StartFragment-->', pClipData); // len = 20
        idxEndFragment := Pos('<!--EndFragment-->', pClipData);
        if (idxStartFragment >= 0) and (idxEndFragment >= idxStartFragment) then
          Result := Copy(pClipData, idxStartFragment + 20, idxEndFragment - idxStartFragment - 20);
      finally GlobalUnlock(hClipData); end;
    finally Win32Check(CloseClipboard); end;
  end;
end; { DSiGetHtmlFormatFromClipboard }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if DSiIsHtmlFormatOnClipboard then
    ShowMessage(DSiGetHtmlFormatFromClipboard)
  else
    ShowMessage('No HTML Format on Clipboard');
end;

initialization
  GCF_HTML := RegisterClipboardFormat('HTML Format');
end.
```

Comment: Call GetLastError to see why GetClipboardData fails. It's probably related to integrity. The data in the clipboard comes from a low integrity process and you are running the IDE elevated perhaps? Anyway, get more facts.

Comment: GetLastError retrieved immediately after the line `hClipData := GetClipboardData(GCF_HTML);`: "ERROR_CLIPBOARD_NOT_OPEN 1418 (0x58A) Thread does not have a clipboard open." This is strange because the preceding line is: `Win32Check(OpenClipboard(0));`

Comment: Could not that be caused by the running Clipboard Format Spy app. for some reason (I don't know how it's implemented)?

Comment: @VictoriaMarotoSilva I have tried also without running it.

Comment: The problem is that `OpenClipboard` will not fail even if another window has the clipboard open (as mentioned in the docs). but the next call to `GetClipboardData` will fail with *"Thread does not have a clipboard open"*. so @Victoria might be right and the Clipboard Format Spy (or other thread) might be holding the clipboard open.

Comment: To reproduce put a `ShowMessage()` right after `Win32Check(OpenClipboard(0));` and run 2 applications at the same time. click on the button on both. `ShowMessage` will appear (`OpenClipboard` will success for both). then click the OK, the second process will fail on `GetClipboardData()` with `"Thread does not have a clipboard open"`

Comment: @kobik so, you are saying the [`OpenClipboard` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649048.aspx) is wrong?  "***OpenClipboard fails if another window has the clipboard open**.*".

Comment: @Remy it appears so. But I only tested with 0 as handle.

Comment: There is a much newer version of `DSIWin32.pas` 1.94 from 2016-10-19 which is contained in the current version of OmniThreadLibrary_3.07.1. The one I've linked to in the first line of my question is much older: 1.66 from 2012-04-20. However, also in this newer version of `DSIWin32.pas` the function `DSiGetHtmlFormatFromClipboard` does not seem to work although I've made sure that no other clipboard programs are running.